# How to make Countdown timer to show same time in all Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, timer

I have created a fragment, that is visible on the top of `4 Activities`, I have created a `Countdown Timer` in my Fragment, Its working fine.

The problems is that, on each Activity timer refreshes, and starts from `00:03:00`, I have created timer for `3 Minutes`, I want it show the same time in all activities, and not refresh itself on each activity.

This is my code.

```
public class myCartFragment extends Fragment {

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_header_fragment, container, false);
        tvTimer= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer= new CounterClass(180000, 1000);
        countDownTimer.start();    
        }


    public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer{
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis= millisUntilFinished;
            String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
                    );    
            tvTimer.setText(hms);
        }
}
```

I am using this fragment in my activities by using following code in my Layout XML file

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calendarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="fragments.myCartFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/header_fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i wouldn't use 4 different timers if there is only one needed. try to just make a single instance of that timer and make each textview get the time of that instance.

Comment: Probably, you need common code to access in all Activities. Can be a singleton class. Refer the value after accessing from each Activity. Which will give the same value in all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the single instance of your CounterClass  throughout all the Activities/Fragments

Use static method to initialize `getInstance` and retrieve values `getFormatedTime()`.

```
public class CounterClass  extends CountDownTimer{

private static String hms;
private static CounterClass instance;

private CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
    super(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
}

public static CounterClass  initInstance(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
    if(instance==null){
        instance =  new CounterClass(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static CounterClass  getInstance() throws Exception{
    if(instance==null){
        throw new Exception("Parameters not initialized. Initiate with initInstance");
    }else{
        return instance;
    }
}

public static String getFormatedTime(){
    return hms;
}
@Override
public void onTick(long l) {

    long millis= l;
    hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
    );
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {

}
}
```

I have modified the code.

Inorder to initiate the CounterClass, do the following.

```
CounterClass counterClass = CounterClass.initInstance(180000, 1000);
counterClass.start();
```

For accessing the previous value

```
try {
      CounterClass counterClass = CounterClass.getInstance();
      Log.i("TAG 222", counterClass.getFormatedTime());
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       // counter class is not initiated , access initInstance
     }
```

As `android.os.CountDownTimer`  does not have default constructor, this is the way we can achieve your requirement

Comment: I used your code, In My Activity Class, i am writing following code, But its returning `null` on `getFormattedTime()` method

Comment: CounterClass counterClass= CounterClass.getInstance(18000,1000);

        tvTimer.setText(CounterClass.getFormattedTime());

Comment: You need to invoke onTick method to get the hms modified. Because onTick only modifies the value and not getInstance.   getInstance is to access the same instance throughout your project

Comment: To be precise countDownTimer.start();  should be called to invoke onTick() method

Comment: I have call `.start()` before, but Its still displaying `Null`

Comment: I have modified the answer with steps.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i take the value of `hms` and place it in `TextView`

Comment: Once you access the getFormatedTime() method from your UI you can get the value. I think its obvious beyond explanation. And moreover that code also I have put along with answer with a try catch.

Comment: Thanks for all the Help :)

Comment: Thanks it retrieve values in multiple activity but how we reset or stop this timer using stop button. I have tried alot after click on stop button when we again click on start button it returns same value where we stop.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to place the timer in your activity and use multiple fragments.
You can add/replace fragments within the activity as you want.

Each fragment can receive the timer's ticks via a **listener (Observer Pattern)**.

**In your activity define:**

```
public interface onTimerTick{
void timerTick(long millisUntilFinished);
}
```

and keep a reference to the **fragment(s)** that implement the interface:

```
List<onTimerTick> listeners=new ArrayList<>();
listeners.add(new Fragment1());
```

**in the timer's onTick:**

```
public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer{
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           for(onTimerTick fragment:listeners){
fragment.timerTick(millisUntilFinished);
}
        }
}
```

**then each fragment:**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements onTimerTick{
@Override
void timerTick(long millisUntilFinished){
//display remaining time
}
```

Another approach is to send a **broadcast** when the timer ticks, then each fragment having a **broadcast receiver** will receive the timer value.

Comment: Thanks, I need to ask few things related to your answer, 
1)Where to write this Code,  `List<onTimerTick> listeners=new ArrayList<>();` and i have only 1 fragment, so what to add this in `List`

Comment: If you have a single fragment, then you don't need to save it in a list, just keep a reference to it.

Comment: so i need to write this interface..` onTimerTick timerTick; `

Comment: You can define the interface in the activity class file or in a separate file